# How do I request a resource (relative path) from the current server?

Tags: c#, asp.net

If I have a relative path that I need to get from the current server. The following does not work because it is not a valid URI.

```
var request = WebRequest.Create("\path_to_resource")
```

I believe that the easiest way would be to put the path in the web.config, however this is easily broken by forgetting to update the config when the application is moved to another server. Is there a better way than?

```
var request = WebRequest.Create(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["root"] + "\path_to_resource");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you can always use something like:

```
private string CurrentDomain()
{
    string currDomain = Request.Url.Scheme + System.Uri.SchemeDelimiter + Request.Url.Host;
    if (Request.Url.Port != 80 && Request.Url.Port != 443)
        currDomain += (":" + Request.Url.Port);
    return currDomain;
}
```

Using these various [Request](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.request.aspx) object properties will give you your current domain name onto which you can append your sub-folders for your resource.

`Request.Url.Scheme` is the `http / https` part of the URL, `System.Uri.SchemeDelimiter` is the `://` part, and the `Request.Url.Host` will be your actual host name (ie. `example.com`).
If your site is running on a non-standard port, the calls to `Request.Url.Port` will add that into the URL "domain name" also.
Note that this is not bullet-proof code, as it assumes your (for example) running SSL (https) on the default port of 443

If you need actual physical file paths, you can use [Server.MapPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524632.aspx) to retrieve the physical file path of the "root" of your ASP.NET application, and append your sub-folders from there.

See also:  [ASP.NET Web Site Paths](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178116.aspx)

Comment: what if the application isn't at the root of the domain?

Comment: If its not at the root you can use: Request.ApplicationPath. So "CurrentDomain() + Request.ApplicationPath + "/MyPage.aspx"